# How to redirect output of a program to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, dataframe

how to redirect output of a file to a dataframe.

this code opens browser and types the given data provided and gets the first data available.

code :

```
selenium pincodes

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import html5lib
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

pin=['mumbai','newyork']

for i in pin :

    url = "https://www.google.com/"
    chromedriver = r"C:\Users\me\chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)


    search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.send_keys(i,'pincode')
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]')))
    elmts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]')
    print(i,elmts[0].text)

    time.sleep(3) 
    driver.quit()
```

this code outputs the following

```
newyork 10001
mumbai 230532
```

how to redirect this output into df like this

```
city      pincode

newyork    10001
mumbai     230532
```

Comment: you can't redirect. You can put items on list - `data.append([i,elmts[0].text])` - and later use all data to create `DataFrame(data)` or you have to create empty `DataFrame` and later append rows.

Comment: help me with the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import html5lib
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

pin=['mumbai','newyork']

df_output = pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"])

for i in pin :

    url = "https://www.google.com/"
    chromedriver = r"C:\Users\me\chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)


    search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.send_keys(i,'pincode')
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]')))
    elmts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]')
    print(i,elmts[0].text)

    df_output = df_output.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=["City", "pincode"], data=[[i,elmts[0].text]]))

    time.sleep(3) 
    driver.quit()
print(df_output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare two arrays and add into dataframe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import html5lib
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

pin=['mumbai','newyork']
#Declare list here
City=[]
PinCode=[]
for i in pin :

    url = "https://www.google.com/"
    chromedriver = r"C:\Users\me\chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)


    search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.send_keys(i,'pincode')
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]')))
    elmts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="IAznY"]//div[@class="title"]')
    #Append the data into list
    City.append(i)
    PinCode.append(elmts[0].text)

#added into dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame({"City":City,"PinCode":PinCode})
print(df)


time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
      City PinCode
0   mumbai  230532
1  newyork   10001
```

Answer (score 0):

executing a script (as a subprocess) from another script and parsing the (redirected) output can technically be done, but that's definitly not the right approach (nor the easiest actually).

Instead, you want to refactor your scripts as [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) in [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), and have one function working on the results of the other.